# Uncall called function before getting called again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to uncall called function before it is called again?On success of ajax call, content is loaded and I call my function (right after html(data) ) because in other case it's not working. If I again load content, function is duplicating and eg. all my alerts show twice. (If I make 10 ajax calls I get 10 alerts instead of one).

I've tried to to call function only once (after first ajax call) but then It work only with first ajax call and stop working after another calls.

The only idea I have in this case is to uncall function before another call but I didn't found nothing.

```
// If I don't call this function in ajax call below code doesn't work
// Ajax loaded content
function readydoc()
{
    $(document).on("change","#example1",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example2",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example3",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example4",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }
}


// MY AJAX CALL
function displayPhoto(photoid){
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/displayphoto.php?photo_id="+photoid
    }).done(function(data) {    
        if (data == false)
        {
            alert ("ERROR");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#content').html(data);
            readydoc(); // Here I call my function
        }
    });
}

// HTML
<div id="content"> <!-- ALL AJAX STUFF GOES HERE <-->
   <div id="example1"></div> <!-- loaded by ajax <-->
   <div id="example2"></div> <!-- loaded by ajax <-->
   <div id="example3"></div> <!-- loaded by ajax <-->
   <div id="example4"></div> <!-- loaded by ajax <-->
</div>
```

Comment: Include your code so we can see what's going on - but it sounds like you're attaching an event handler multiple times

Comment: There is a lot of code but I will try to chose the most important things. One sec...

Comment: I like how you refer to your function as her :)

Comment: @Caner Akdeniz I'm JS begginer, and this language overwhelms me :) I've added the code.

Comment: Seems like you are binding the same change events again and again every time you get done with your ajax call. With `.on()` method, you do not need to call the event declarations every time you add dynamic content. Declaring them once on page load would be enough.

Comment: @Caner Akdeniz are you suggesting that I should put `<script src="js/global.js"></script>` inside `displayphoto.php` and load it on every ajax call ? Because actually It's work perfect only In this way.

Comment: @WalterWhite as suggested in the answer, just move the declarations out of your `readydoc()` function.

Comment: Finally It's works! Thank you all. Now I know where I was making mistake. It was a valuable lesson for the future. I'm going back to my HUGE code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comments, that is how your code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("change","#example1",function(){
     // SOME CODE
   }
   $(document).on("change","#example2",function(){
     // SOME CODE
   }
   $(document).on("change","#example3",function(){
     // SOME CODE
   }
   $(document).on("change","#example4",function(){
     // SOME CODE
   } 
});

function readydoc()
{
   //SOME OTHER CODE YOU WANT TO TRIGGER AFTER EVERY AJAX CALL
}

// MY AJAX CALL
function displayPhoto(photoid){
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/displayphoto.php?photo_id="+photoid
    }).done(function(data) {    
        if (data == false)
        {
            alert ("ERROR");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#content').html(data);
            readydoc(); // Here I call my function
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time your ajax call finishes, you're executing `readydoc` which is attaching the event handlers.  Each call will attach more and more event handlers.  Instead, call your event attaching function [once on page load](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
   //this will run once when the page has loaded
   $(document).on("change","#example1",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example2",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example3",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }

   $(document).on("change","#example4",function(){
    // SOME CODE
   }
});
```

Remove the call to `readydoc` from within your ajax call - it's not needed.  This will attach your event handlers only once, regardless of how many times the ajax call is run.

Comment: So I have to rewrite the code because example1 and example2 must be in readydoc() to work proper because readydoc() have stuff that they need. But I'm not sure is this possible with them outside the function.